# Why do I get flutter exception when printing variable in Text widget but not to console?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm learning flutter but here's a strange one for me.  Whenever I send my widget a string, I can print it to the console appropriately however I can't print the variable to the UI in the Text widget.  Text without variables print to each card just fine.

Thanks!

```
Class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp();

  static const String _title = 'Flutter Code Sample';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        title: _title,
        home: Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(title: const Text(_title)),
            body: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                MyStatelessWidget("dog"),
                MyStatelessWidget("cat"),
                MyStatelessWidget("mouse"),
                Expanded(
                  child: FittedBox(
                    fit: BoxFit.contain,
                    child: const FlutterLogo(),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            )));
  }
}

class MyStatelessWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyStatelessWidget(this.names);

  final String names;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Card(
        child: InkWell(
          splashColor: Colors.green,
          onTap: () {
            print('$names'); // This works fine
          },
          child: const SizedBox(
            width: 350.0,
            height: 100.0,
            child: const Card(child: Text('I want here to print $names')), // but I get an error.
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: The `const` in `const SizedBox` and `const Card` means that those objects are intended to be compile-time constants.  However, you've made the `Card` widget depend on `'$names'`, which cannot be resolved until runtime.  This should have resulted in a compile-time failure, not a runtime exception.

Comment: That fixed it. Thank you very much.